# jQuery .on( 'ended' ) not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I am facing an issue with event handlers in iOS mobile Safari.

I have a button that is bound on click to play a series of different sound files.

The code works as intended on Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari.  However on mobile devices it only plays the first sound in the series.

I have a feeling the mobile Safari doesn't fire the "ended" event trigger when the audio is done playing.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  Any suggestions?

Again, it's working as intended on every browser except for iOS mobile Safari.

The code is below.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.audio-button').click( function(){
  $('.audio-button').toggle();
  $('.disabled-audio').toggle();
  var pinyinlinks = $( this ).attr('audio');
  var pinyinsplit = pinyinlinks.split(',');
  pinyinsplit = pinyinsplit.map(function(el) { 
     return 'http://mandarin.cards/wp-content/themes/cards/audio/' + el; 
  });
  console.log(pinyinsplit);
  var pinyincount = pinyinsplit.length;
  if ( pinyincount > 1 ){
   var myaudio = [];
   var next = 0;
   for ( var i = 0; i < pinyincount; i++ ) {
    myaudio[i] = new Audio( pinyinsplit[i]);
    if ( i != pinyincount - 1 ){
     $( myaudio[i] ).on('ended', function(){;
      next = next + 1;
      myaudio[next].play();
     })
    };
   }
   myaudio[0].play();
   setTimeout(function(){
    $('.disabled-audio').toggle();
    $('.audio-button').toggle();
   }, 2300);
  } else {
   var myaudio = new Audio( pinyinlinks );
   myaudio.play();
  }
 } )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onClick="" class="audio-button" style="cursor: pointer;" audio="ni_3.mp3,hao_3.mp3">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg text-yellow" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read Word">
     Read Word
 </span>
</span>
<span class="disabled-audio" style="display: none;">
 <span class="fa-stack fa-lg text-dk-gray" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read Word">
      Read Word
 </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem with this code.

**Safari Mobile had a problem with me attaching the event handlers within the same for loop that was creating the audio elements**.  The event handler was firing a function that played an audio element that did not yet exist.   It didn't cause a problem for most browsers, but I think this caused the problem with Safari which may have stricter guidelines.

**The solution was to break up the loop into two separate loops, one to create the audio elements, and one to attach the event handlers:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.audio-button').click( function(){
    $('.audio-button').toggle();
    $('.disabled-audio').toggle();
    var pinyinlinks = $( this ).attr('audio');
    var pinyinsplit = pinyinlinks.split(',');
    pinyinsplit = pinyinsplit.map(function(el) { 
        return 'http://mandarin.cards/wp-content/themes/cards/audio/' + el; 
    });
    console.log(pinyinsplit);
    var pinyincount = pinyinsplit.length;
    if ( pinyincount > 1 ){
        var myaudio = [];
        var next = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < pinyincount; i++ ) {
            myaudio[i] = new Audio( pinyinsplit[i]);
            myaudio[i].load();
        }
        function playnext( element, index, array ) {
            $( element ).on('ended', function(){;
                    next = next + 1;
                    myaudio[next].play();
                })
        };
        myaudio.forEach( playnext );
        myaudio[0].play();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.disabled-audio').toggle();
            $('.audio-button').toggle();
        }, 2300);
    } else {
        var myaudio = new Audio( pinyinlinks );
        myaudio.play();
    }
} )});
```

Working as intended now.